# Can bouncing batteries tell you if they are charged or not?

Tags: physics, battery

I saw [this article](http://qz.com/375807/scientists-prove-you-can-bounce-a-battery-to-test-if-its-still-good/) this morning, and while it seemed fairly legitimate, I was skeptical about it. The claim is that if you drop a battery (flat end down) it will bounce higher/longer if the charge is gone then if it's fresh.

I figure if I had a volt-meter or the like I could probably test this myself, but I don't. A bit of googling didn't provide any results that I had a high amount of confidence in.

Comment: If you bounce it hard enough I'll guarantee it's uncharged.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, bouncing batteries tell you if they are charged or not.

The claim started with this YouTube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y_m6p99l6ME&feature=youtu.be):

[image]

> How To Test a AA battery, Easiest Way For Any Battery Fast, Easy!

After it went viral, scientists in the US have been curious, and later they confirmed that a simple bounce test can be used as a technique if a battery is charged.

A team led by [Daniel Steingart](http://www.princeton.edu/mae/people/faculty/steingart/) of Princeton University, published their paper [here](http://pubs.rsc.org/en/Content/ArticleLanding/2015/TA/c5ta01576f#!divAbstract), you can read it [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7dmym4cK6ABYTg1Z3Q3T3FySmc/view?usp=sharing).

As quoted by the study:

> **Recently there has been popular interest in the tendency of
> an alkaline AA battery to bounce after being dropped on its end
> when discharged to full capacity**, compared to a flat landing
> with minimal bounce when the battery is “as-received”. In this
> paper the coefficient of restitution (COR) of an alkaline AA
> battery is measured at various depths of discharge by dropping
> the battery in a controlled fashion and observing the subsequent
> bouncing, and the change in COR is then compared to
> spatially resolved energy-dispersive X-ray diffraction (EDXRD)
> that was performed in situ on equivalent alkaline AA batteries.
> Our measurements show that this simple bounce test provides a
> considerable amount of information of the structure of the
> battery's Zn anode, rivaling the sensitivity of in situ EDXRD in
> detection of ZnO formation.

> **This discovery shows that nondestructive
> acoustic testing of batteries can provide valuable
> information about a battery's health and state of charge (SOC).
> Studies performed on other bobbin cell geometries (AAA, C and
> D alkaline cells) yield similar results.**

According to [scientificamerican.com](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/bounce-a-battery-to-learn-if-it-is-still-good-really-video/), Daniel Steingart said:

> We needed XRD to explain why the bounce changes this way, but once the correlation is made, a secondary **school physics experiment can indicate where and how reactions are occurring in the battery**.

Comment: But note that this only seems to apply to (non-rechargable) alkaline batteries.

Comment: Yes, I guess...

Answer (score 1):

This paper [**Bouncing Alkaline Batteries: A Basic Solution**](https://www.bnl.gov/isd/documents/88597.pdf)  confirms the causal link between battery bounce characteristics and state of charge for selected battery chemistries and describes the mechanism imvolved. They say:

- The coefficient of restitution of alkaline batteries has been shown to increase as a function of
  depth of discharge. In this work, using non-destructive mechanical testing, the change in coefficient
  of restitution is compared to in situ energy-dispersive x-ray diffraction data to determine the cause
  of the macroscopic change in coefficient of restitution. The increase in coefficient of restitution
  correlates to the formation of a percolation pathway of ZnO within the anode of the cell, and that
  the coefficient of restitution saturates at a value of 0.63 ± .05 at 50% state of charge when the
  anode has densified into porous ZnO solid. Of note is the sensitivity of coefficient of restitution to
  the amount of ZnO formation that rivals the sensitivity of in situ energy-dispersive x-ray diffraction
  spectroscopy.
  and
- In this paper the coefficient of restitution (COR) of an alkaline AA battery is measured at various
  depths of discharge by dropping the battery in a controlled fashion and observing the subsequent bouncing. Our
  measurements show that this simple bounce test can provide a considerable amount of information of the structure of
  the battery’s Zn anode, rivaling the sensitivity of in situ energy-dispersive x-ray spectroscopy (EDXRD) in detection
  of ZnO formation. This discovery shows that non-destructive acoustic testing of batteries can provide valuable
  information about a battery’s health and state of charge (SOC).
  And
- The densification of the anode affects the mechanical properties of the battery. The COR, which measures
  the elasticity of a collision between an object and a rigid object, is one such mechanical property that can be determined
  as shown in Eq. 5.
  COR = sqrt(h2/h1)
  where h1 is the drop height, and h2 is the maximum bounce height determined from Eq. 1. Using the bounce test
  described previously, the COR of alkaline batteries was measured through full discharge

**Authors institutions:** Andlinger Center for Energy and The Environment,
Princeton University, , Department of Physics, Rutgers University, Piscataway, New Jersey, University of New York Energy Institute, New York, New York, Department of Chemical Engineering, City College of New York, New York, New York, Sustainable Technologies Division, Brookhaven National Laboratory, Upton, New York, National Synchrotron Light Source, Brookhaven National Laboratory, Upton, New York 11973, USA††

**______________________________________________________**

It definitely works for Alkaline batteries, which is what the detailed explanation relates to. THe probable reasons are well explained by the information provided by georgechalhoub. I'm just adding the observations of an experienced competent professional observer [tm] :-).

I am an electrical engineer with a Masters degree in EE and 50+ years experience with electronics. (Yes, we did have electronics "way back then").  I, too, was extremely sceptical when I read of this phenomenon. However, testing with dozens (probably ~= 50) of AA Alkaline batteries of a number of brands and states of charge showed and extremely large difference between fully charged and well used batteries. I did not carry out extensive tests with varying degrees of use - batteries here tend to be new, moderately well used or well used. Flattened to within a few mAh of their life tend to be thrown out asap.

As a means of sorting through a bag of mixed batteries to find unused ones this method works superbly. It is probably no quicker than using a test meter, bt hard flat surfaces are often easier to come by than multimeters "in the field".

---

Here are a series of [reasonably well done experiments](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qrGV7zKEdtU) and battery dis-assemblies in a you tube video. This appears convincing but, of course, could be "cooked" if anyone wanted to spend the very extensive effort required to falsify results. There is no good reason to disbelieve what is shown here, but it's not peer reviewed and doesn't have a recognised institution name on it.

Comment: We don't allow answers based on personal expertise. Can you find some reputable sources that sustain your answer?

Comment: @Sklivvz I am well aware of the strange, in my estimation, tendency of this forum to allow personal accounts that are reported from elsewhere but not by people reporting directly, even when they carefully describe circumstances of testing. If you wish to check how reputable my source is  you can look at eg [this web page](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/3288/russell-mcmahon) or [this list of references](https://www.google.co.nz/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%22russell+mcmahon%22+apptechnz+electronic) as a measure of bona fides. Should such not suffice, as I imagine may well prove to be the case ..

Comment: @Sklivvz  ... disallow as you see fit. If you cannot allow eg Stack Exchange EE to become a source of credibility in its own right, what merit is there in allowing of material from other sources, which are often enough less reputable. Anyone who chooses to disbelieve an account that I offer on tests that I say I have carried out, where the procedures and degree (or lack) of formality are at least summarised, may do so as they choose. I suggest that the loss will usually be theirs. | I have read other accounts of tests carried out by persons who I consider competent and reliable. As ...

Comment: ... each of these is based on "personal expertise" we end up with (semi) infinite regress. Presumably one needs the name of an institution or faceless webpage to add notional credibility to such reports?

Comment: The reference you added in the question is of poor quality, in my opinion, but it is a reference. The ones in the comments, instead are useless. They establish your authority, which was not in doubt in the first place. The problem is we don't allow arguments from authority.

Comment: @Sklivvz - I have long been amused by the "Argument from authority fallacy" fallacy. I'm aware that it is generously applied in many circles. But it's as good a fallacy fallacy as most. It's hard to know where it ends - and I suspect that if applied with due rigour (or rigor for those not here in the antipodes) then it would be exceeding hard to find any reference that one could allowably rely on. I DO agree that blindly relying on those who have been correct often before in their chosen field to be right again even in their own field is potentially dangerous - but if the authority of none ...

Comment: ...is acceptable to establish precedence then it is an extremely hard row to hoe to reach a place of meaningful reference. The current peer review process in all too many areas **does** demonstrate the merit of your position, unfortunately :-).

Comment: I understand your point - typically we rely on qualitative studies if possible, but the argument from *personal* authority is beyond what we can accept in general (think about things like "I'm a ufologist and I can certify aliens exist")